# Two different solutions for a question about conditional probability . .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bag containing 4 white and 6 black balls , 2 balls are drawn .

Find the probability that :

a) one ball is white and the other is black (without replacement)

b) one ball is white and the other is black (with replacement)

My Solution :

a) P(1st white and 2nd black ) + P(1st black and 2nd white)
= $\frac{4}{10} . \frac{6}{9} + \frac{6}{10}.\frac{4}{9}$

b) P(1st white and 2nd black ) + P(1st black and 2nd white)
= $\frac{4}{10} . \frac{6}{10} + \frac{6}{10}.\frac{4}{10}$

Solution I have found in a lecture notes :

a) P(1st white and 2nd black ) + P(1st black and 2nd white)
= $\frac{4}{10} . \frac{6}{9} + \frac{6}{10}.\frac{4}{9}$

b) P(1st white and 2nd black )
= $\frac{4}{10} . \frac{6}{10} $

My Question is for part b) Is my solution is correct or the other solution in the lecture notes

Another question .
I have found in a lecture note that  we have two definitions for the ace

that some consider that we have only one ace  in 52 deck of cards that is ace of spade and

the others are not called aces but called one of heart or one of club or one daimond Is that correct ?

The definition o]for the ace is that we have four aces .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I expect the $b$ answers are for different questions.  Yours is correct if the question is as you stated: "what is the probability that one ball is black and the other white?"  The other is correct if the question is "what is the probability that the first draw is white and the second draw is black?"  As to the language question, in English it is unusual to refer to aces as ones.  Indeed, aces are often considered "high", meaning that they are ranked higher than Kings.  Alternatively, aces can be consider "low" (equivalent to a $1$) or sometimes both.

Comment: How many aces in 52 deck of cards ? Should I say one or 4 ?

Comment: There are $4$ aces in a standard $52$ card deck.  There are $4$ of each rank, from $2$ to $A$.